# Elasticsearch using shingle filter with synonym

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following documents:

- `south africa`
- `north africa`

I want to retrieve my "south africa" document from:

- `s africa` (a)
- `southafrica` (b)
- `safrica` (c)

I defined the followings filters and analyzers:

```
POST test_index
{
  "settings": {
   "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "south,s",
            "north,n"
          ]
        },
        "shingle_filter": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3,
            "token_separator": ""
          }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_shingle": {
          "type":      "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":    ["shingle_filter"]
        },
        "my_shingle_synonym": {
          "type":      "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":    ["shingle_filter", "synonym_filter"]
        },
        "my_synonym_shingle": {
          "type":      "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":    ["synonym_filter", "shingle_filter"]
        }
    }
  } 
  },
  "mappings": {}
}
```

1) With **my_shingle** `south africa` will be indexed as `south`, `southafrica`, `africa`

2) With **my_shingle_synonym** `south africa` will be indexed as `south`, `s`, `southafrica`, `africa`

3) With **my_synonym_shingle** `south africa` will be indexed as `south`, `souths`, `southsafrica`, `s`, `safrica`, `africa`

So with

- (1) I will find b
- (2) I will find a, b
- (3) I will find a, c

I want `south africa` to be indexed as: `south`, `s`, `southafrica`, `safrica`, `africa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** have to output all possible tokens as per your requirement. Your problem can be solved by using different analyzers on [multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html).

You would define `mapping` of your desired field like this.

```
"mappings": {
    "your_mapping": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_shingle",
          "fields": {
            "synonym": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_synonym_shingle"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

sample document to index

```
PUT test_index/your_mapping/1
{
  "name" : "south africa"
}
```

then you would query on all variants of name field with [wildcard expression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field).

```
GET test_index/your_mapping/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "name*"
      ],
      "query": "safrica"
    }
  }
}
```