# How to tokenize a sentence based on maximum number of words in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, tokenize

I have a string like "This is a beautiful day"
What tokenizer or what combination between tokenizer and token filter should I use to produce output that contains terms that have a maximum of 2 words? Ideally, the output should be:
"This, This is, is, is a, a, a beautiful, beautiful, beautiful day, day"
So far, I have tried all built-in tokenizer, the 'pattern' tokenizer seems the one I can use, but I don't know how to write a regex pattern for my case. Any help?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42991748/4604579

Comment: Thank you. And this link might help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681178/elasticsearch-using-shingle-filter-with-synonym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're looking for [shingle token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As what @Oleksii said.
in your case max_shingle_size = 2 (which is the default), and min_shingle_size = 1.